# Display a condition from an array

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Need help guys, below is a var_dump array, I am very noob in php and I am very confused on how to do this, basically all I need is a condition

```
$fittin_colour_image = get_field('featured_images', get_the_ID());
```

Above is a code using ACF

```
var_dump($fittin_colour_image);
```

below is the result

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'fitting_colour' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Black' (length=5)
      'image' => string 'http://localhost/mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/image-black.jpg' (length=101)
      'image_description' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'fitting_colour' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'White' (length=5)
      'image' => string 'http://localhost/mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/image-white.png' (length=100)
      'image_description' => string '' (length=0)
```

I want to have a condition like this

if this array has a color "Black" then display its image

I am currently using this code

```
if ($fittin_colour_image[0]['fitting_colour'][0] == 'Black') {
echo $fittin_colour_image[0]['image'];
}
```

its a bit of a hassle since every time I change the condition I change the [0], sorry but I am confused now, don't know what to say, please help

Comment: If you want this regardless of which items contains “black” - then loop over all of them. If you find “black”, you set a flag, echo the image, and break out of the loop. After the loop, you check if your flag indicated that “black” was found - if not, do whatever else needs doing then (if anything.)

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. Instead of hard-coding the index (`0` in your case) you can, instead, loop over the array and display the image:

```
foreach ($fittin_colour_image as $image) {
    if ($image['fitting_colour'][0] == 'Black') {
        echo $image['image'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, tried your code and I got a "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() i", I think its something to do when there is no array or empty

Comment: If `$fittin_colour_image` is sometimes *not* an array, then wrap it in a check: `if (is_array($fittin_colour_image)) { /* above code here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

test this

```
$fittin_colour_image = get_field('featured_images', get_the_ID());

if(!empty($fittin_colour_image)){ // Test if array not empty
    foreach ($fittin_colour_image as $image) {
        if(!empty($image['fitting_colour'][0]) && $image['fitting_colour'][0] === 'Black'){
            echo '<img src="'.$image['image'].'" alt="'.$image['image_description'].'" />';
        }
    }
}
```